# Padlock with triangle only on homepage (chrome, firefox, IE, safari)

Tags: ssl, mixed-content

I've looked into it a little and some people were saying it's because HTTP needs to be changed to HTTPS for images, etc.

Is there a tool I can use that can troubleshoot my SSL issue?

Can anyone tell me why this site (https://epharmacies.com/) has the padlock with the triangle and not just the lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

From a quick glance at the source code for the homepage, you can see some references to non-secure (HTTP) resources.  See below for a snippet:

> DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://epharmacies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/eDS-blue-pill-bg-2.png&#039;
>
> background-image:
>   url(http://epharmacies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/eDS-blue-pill-bg-2.png);">

**SSL/Certificate Tools**

[Comodo SSL Certificate Troubleshooter](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Troubleshooter/Step/View/2)

---

The lock with yellow warning triangle icon signifies that although the connection to the site is encrypted, there are other resources on the page which are not secure, which can be viewed by others while in transit and modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.

From [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1):

> **Site Identity information:**
>
> Google Chrome can see the site’s certificate, but the site uses a weak
>   security setup (SHA-1 signatures), so your connection might not be
>   private.
>
> Proceed with caution. These are common mistakes in websites'
>   configurations, but that doesn't guarantee that your connection is
>   secure.
>
> **Connection information:**
>
> Your connection to the site is encrypted, but Google Chrome has found
>   something on the page that could be
>   unwanted images or ads. We suggest you don't enter private or personal
>   information on this page.

Comment: yeah I read that also, i'm trying to fix this...

Comment: nope, but I have access.

Comment: Also just added link for Comodo/Addtrust SSL troubleshooting (the site's certificate issuer).

Comment: okay will check it out

Comment: See my last edit.

Comment: thanks! making some changes, will let you know what happens

Comment: Looks like you're all set.  Glad I could point you in the right direction.